# How to get notified of incoming RSS feed items in Outlook 2010?

Tags: rss, microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm currently using Outlook 2010 to fetch RSS feeds. It's working perfectly, but one point is missing.

For emails, I get a little notification in the systray and as an small OSD. For RSS feed items not.

Is there any option to get this kind of notification?

I'm not interested in other software or plugins for Firefox.

Comment: Not making an answer as I am not 100% sure and can not run outlook to test, but have you taken a look in the rules and alerts section to see if you can set anything upon new RSS items?

Comment: I didn't thought of it but more of a general option...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will have to create a new rule for this:

1- Open the Rules and Alerts dialog:

[image]

2- Click the New Rule... button

[image]

3- Follow the wizard to recreate the same rule as follow:

[image]